# Setting up a pom.xml for vscode java project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I've got an Eclipse Java project and am trying to move it to VSCode.

VSCode doesn't seem to import the Eclipse project - so I decided to create a pom.xml file.

My project is basically a bunch of java files in the root folder and I would like the class files to be stored in a specific sub-folder. I've got some dependencies on some external jar files.

Can a kind soul take a look at my pom.xml file and what needs be fixed.

Right now with the current pom.xml - it copies the root folder contents and saves it into the output folder - no class files.

I've got the RedHat java extension loaded into VSCode.

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.eclipseworkspace.projects</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>    
    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory> <!-- save to folder -->
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory> <!-- location of my source java files -->
  </build>

  <!-- not sure where to specify the included jar files for the compile -->

</project>
```